# How result is bind in UNION prepared statement in Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, union

How Mysqli bind result if there is row select in both union query. suppose there is query like this

```
        $construct .="(rated in ($age_csph) or rated in ($age_csph)
          or rated in ($age_csph) or rated in ($age_csph) or rated in ($age_csph)
          or rated in ($age_csph) or rated in ($age_csph))";

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("(SELECT id,name,year FROM info WHERE $construct) union all (SELECT id,name,year FROM show WHERE $construct) ORDER BY year desc"); 

    array_unshift($total_params, $param_string);  // prepend the type values string

    $ref = [];  // add references
    foreach ($total_params as $i => $v) {
        $ref[$i] = &$total_params[$i];  // pass by reference as required/advised by the manual
    }

    call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $ref);    

      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($id1,name1,$year1);

      $count = 0;
      while ($stmt->fetch()){
       echo $year1;
           $count++;
        } 
        $foundnum=$count; 

       }
```

I want to know how result is binded if there is match in both select.
there is only one

```
$stmt->bind_result($id1,name1,$year1);
```

please someone explain this to me.

Comment: $age_csph is variable containing placeholders.

Comment: Okay, than you need to bind for every placeholder. Are you getting errors when you execute?

Comment: No everything is working fine no error. Results also displayed.

Comment: I want to know how result bind if there is match on both tables

Comment: @vinay, if you really need `union` and want to differentiate the results per row, then add a `ref` like field in each select with value as `table_name`. it can be like `select 'info' as ref, id, xxx ... union all select 'show' as ref, ...`

Comment: @vinay: check for the use of `join` if both tables have a relation.